# How member functions access your objects?

Tags: javascript

An example of the code for the current situation is as follows:

```js
const vm = require('vm');
class A {
  constructor(path) {
    this.myPath = path;
    this.sandbox = {
      myFunc: this.myFunc
    };
    this.context = vm.createContext(this.sandbox);
  }

  myFunc(n) {
    console.log(this.myPath + n); // this => not 'A' class
  }

  run() {
    var text = "myFunc(1);";
    vm.runInContext(text, this.context);
  }
}

let a = new A("1234");
a.run();
```

Without adding myPath to sandbox and context what should I do to get 'myPath' object from 'myFunc'?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (simplified example):

```js
class A {
  constructor(path) {
    this.myPath = path;

  }

  myFunc(n) {
    const path = this.myPath + n; // this => not 'A' class
    console.log(path);
    return path;
  }

  run() {
    var text = "myFunc(1);";
  }
}

let a = new A("1234");
a.run();

let b = a.myFunc("test");

console.log(b);
```

By returning the string from `myFunc()` you can optionally assign it to another variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Should a function be called to assign to an unconditional variable?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. For example, if that variable can only be generated by that function, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, basically you cannot read what is in console with Javascript. But you could rewrite `console.log` function and store what is logged. Something like:

```js
console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function(){
    console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
    console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
}

class A {
  constructor(path) {
    this.myPath = path;
  }

  myFunc(n) {
    console.log(this.myPath + n);
  }
}

let myClass = new A("path");

myClass.myFunc("_foo");

let myPath = console.logs[0][0].replace("_foo", "");

console.stdlog(myPath);
```

In this way, `console.logs` contains all the string logged, while `console.stdlog` allows you to log without store value logged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'll try using the console log.